# Multiple React HOCs with flow

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom, flow-typed

I'm adding flow type checking to a code base. I've been able to work through most of the issues, but I'm hung up on errors thrown by a component using two higher order components. A working repo of the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/zachwolf/flow-react-router-dom-test/blob/master/src/Button.js#L24-L28), but the simplified component in question looks like this:

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles'

type Props = {
  content: string,
  classes: {
    [string]: string,
  },
}

class Button extends React.Component<Props> {
  render () {
    return (
      <button className={this.props.classes.main}>
        {this.props.content}
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles({
  main: {
    background: 'red',
  }
})(withRouter(Button))
```

Errors I'm seeing:

```
$ flow
Launching Flow server for /Users/flow-react-router-dom-test
Spawned flow server (pid=79843)
Logs will go to /private/tmp/flow/XXXXXXXflow-react-router-dom-test.log
Library type error:
flow-typed/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js:144
144:     Component: React$ComponentType<{| ...ContextRouter, ...P |}>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with
 14: class Button extends React.Component<Props> {
                                          ^^^^^ object type. See: src/Button.js:14
  Property `classes` is incompatible:
     19:           <Button content="click me" />
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. This type is incompatible with. See: src/App.js:19
                    v
      9:   classes: {
     10:     [string]: string,
     11:   },
           ^ object type. See: src/Button.js:9

Library type error:
flow-typed/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js:144
144:     Component: React$ComponentType<{| ...ContextRouter, ...P |}>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with
 14: class Button extends React.Component<Props> {
                                          ^^^^^ object type. See: src/Button.js:14
  Property `content` is incompatible:
     19:           <Button content="click me" />
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. This type is incompatible with. See: src/App.js:19
      8:   content: string,
                    ^^^^^^ string. See: src/Button.js:8

Error: src/App.js:19
 19:           <Button content="click me" />
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React element `Button`
 19:           <Button content="click me" />
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of React element `Button`. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
144:     Component: React$ComponentType<{| ...ContextRouter, ...P |}>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. See lib: flow-typed/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js:144
```

If I use either of the HOCs independently, there are no errors reported.

Alternatively, if I edit the module definition in `flow-react-router-dom-test/flow-typed/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js` to remove the exact object definition, it passes. So:

```
declare export function withRouter<P>(
-  Component: React$ComponentType<{ ...ContextRouter, ...P }>
+  Component: React$ComponentType<{| ...ContextRouter, ...P |}>
): React$ComponentType<P>;
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?